# Save HTML tag in json without encoding

Tags: c#, html

I am generating a json file using c#.
One of the properties is a text: "
paragraph text 1

".
When I save the json file, the text is converted into this:
`"\u003cp\u003eparagraph text 1\u003c/p\u003e"`.
I would like to preserve the original text. I have an entity named Field. It looks like this:

```
public partial class Field
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("identifier")]
        public string identifier { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("isEditorDialogOpen", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public bool? isEditorDialogOpen { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("paragraphHeight", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string paragraphHeight { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("integrationID")]
        public string integrationID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("hint")]
        public string hint { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("tooltip")]
        public string tooltip { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("validations")]
        public object[] validations { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("permission")]
        public string permission { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("maskingViewer")]
        public string maskingViewer { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("defaultValue")]
        public object[] defaultValue { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("width")]
        public string width { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("editedParagraph", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string editedParagraph { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("label")]
        public string label { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("stepIdx")]
        public long stepIdx { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("blockIdx")]
        public long blockIdx { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("rowIdx")]
        public long rowIdx { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("readOnly", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public bool? readOnly { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("clearable", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public bool? clearable { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("required", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public bool? fieldRequired { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("maxLength", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
        public string maxLength { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fieldIdx", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public long? fieldIdx { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("shownInPdfMode", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public bool? shownInPdfMode { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is the json:

```
"fields": [{
    "name": "editor.fields.paragraph",
    "identifier": "paragraph_kdg3wty6",
    "type": "paragraph",
    "isEditorDialogOpen": false,
    "paragraphHeight": "auto",
    "integrationID": "yobi1_a",
    "hint": "",
    "tooltip": "",
    "validations": [],
    "permission": "both",
    "maskingViewer": "none",
    "defaultValue": [],
    "width": "full",
    "editedParagraph": "\u003cp\u003eparagraph text 1\u003c/p\u003e",
    "label": "",
    "stepIdx": 0,
    "blockIdx": 0,
    "rowIdx": 1,
    "readOnly": null,
    "clearable": null,
    "fieldRequired": null,
    "maxLength": null,
    "fieldIdx": null,
    "shownInPdfMode": null
}]
```

And this is how I save the file:

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(field);
                //File.WriteAllText(destination, json);
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(destination, FileMode.Create), Encoding.Unicode))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(json);
                }
```

I tried saving the file as text under any encoding format with no success.

Comment: Please ensure you _edit your question_ instead of providing additional information as a comment.

Comment: sorry. pls view the edited question :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use  `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert` class instead of `JavaScriptSerializer` :

```
var field = new Field() {
   editedParagraph = "<p>this is my text</p>"
};
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(field,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
           
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

the result will be :

```
{
  "name": null,
  "identifier": null,
  "type": null,
  "integrationID": null,
  "hint": null,
  "tooltip": null,
  "validations": null,
  "permission": null,
  "maskingViewer": null,
  "defaultValue": null,
  "width": null,
  "editedParagraph": "<p>this is my text</p>",
  "label": null,
  "stepIdx": 0,
  "blockIdx": 0,
  "rowIdx": 0
}
```

Comment: Should i encode the entire text or just the 'editedParagraph' property?

Comment: The Deserilize is done in a different place, which i dont have access to. I need to save the json with the original text.

Comment: Ali Bigdeli - c#